# Error in publishing CocosBuilder scene in cocos2d 3.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

I am new for Xcode, Cocos2d, and I am making my first steps in CocosBuilder. I am learning from available online tutorials including [RayWenderlich Game Development tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com). While I am copying the code, sometimes I've noticed that authors miss some points, which are not obvious for new developer. In tutorial **Introduction to CocosBuilder**, I can't go through putting scene (*.ccbi) into Xcode I have cocos2d 3.1.0. My code:

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    CCNode * menu = [CCBReader nodeGraphFromFile:@"MainMenuScene.ccbi"];
    CCScene * scene = [CCScene node];
    [scene addChild:menu];
    return scene;
}
```

Xcode doesn't recognize nodeGraphFromFile even if I have made `#import "CCBReader.h"` and also tried another method sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile also doesn't recognize.

```
CCScene *s= [CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:@"MainMenuScene.ccbi"];
```

Can anyone help to show how it look full code of publishing scene from CocosBuilder to cocos2d 3.1.0 version, I would much appreciate.

Unfortunately I can't upload my screenshots.

Comment: Please provide the link to the actual tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The CocosBuilder project is deprecated**, meaning it is [no longer in development](https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder) (last update May 2013). You can still use CB to create applications with cocos2d-iphone v2.x though, but it won't work with cocos2d-iphone v3.

So in short: you can't use CocosBuilder with cocos2d-iphone v3. There will always be a host of problems associated with trying to make it work, and odds are it will not be possible without modifying the cocos2d engine itself respectively the designs in CB will not match what you get when running the app.

You do have alternative options though:

- For cocos2d-iphone v3 use [**SpriteBuilder**](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/download), the successor to CocosBuilder. You will easily find [tutorials for SB](http://www.spritebuilder.com/getting-started/) and in a couple of months my *Learn SpriteBuilder* book will be available, too. SpriteBuilder itself is available on the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/spritebuilder/id784912885).
- Cocos2d-x users should be using [**Cocos Studio**](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/download). SpriteBuilder does not support cocos2d-x.

The SpriteBuilder option also does not require you to manually add the CCBReader files, as they are part of cocos2d v3 which is why there will likely be various conflicts/errors if you try to add the CocosBuilder CCBReader files to a v3 project. SpriteBuilder releases are synchronized with cocos2d-iphone releases so there will not be version-mismatch issues, plus SB can update existing projects to the latest cocos2d-iphone version.

Note however that SpriteBuilder can not import projects or CCB files previously created with CocosBuilder.

Comment: Thank you much for clarification and know I see the whole picture! I hope that authors of tutorials will make such comments and warning inside of their tutorials, so newbies will not hit their heads to wall  due to mismatch of commands between various versions.

Answer (score 0):

As a checklist,

Make sure you have the CCBReader.h added to your project.
It is available here.
https://github.com/cocos2d/CCBReader

Then,

All the ccbi files and other resources should also be added to the project.

Once done, your above code should work.

Start the scene as follows

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:newScene];
```

Comment: Neither of those items in your list will solve Xcode's inability to recognise the methods.  The first will cause the compiler to barf in `#import "CCBReader.h"` and the other will cause a runtime error, not a compile-time error.

Comment: Agreed, but my assumption is that the code has been copy-pasted. So the person must not have noticed the compiler error near 'import' and just reporting the one near this code.

Comment: Yes, CCBReader.h has been included and imported into the running class *.m, also ccbi files also added to project. And one distracting moment I faced with learning cocos2d is that by changing of version, they also change name of command, for instance in lesson was written "Director" (ver 2.x), while in version of cocos2d 3.x it comes like "CCDirector"

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice you were using v3. You might need to downgrade to cocos2d.2.x or using sprite builder instead.